# c++ if else statement in switch case - explanation

Tags: c++

just started learning.
And i have a question about if else in switch statement

here is the code

```
    switch (operation)
{
        case '+': 
        result = num1 + num2;
        cout << result << endl;
        break;

        case '-':
            result= num1-num2; cout << result<< endl; break;

        case '*':
            result= num1 * num2;
            cout << result<< endl;
            break;

        case '/':

            if (num2 == 0)
            {
                cout << "num2 cannot be zero - division with zero is not possible!\n"; 
            }else{
                result= num1/num2;
            }
            cout << result << endl;

            break;




default:
    cout << "message!" << endl;
    break;
}
```

ok this code is generating error - Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'result' is being used without being initialized.

if i change code and add break after  a nessage about division not possible with 0

```
            case '/':

            if (num2 == 0)
            {
                cout << "num2 cannot be zero - division with zero is not possible!\n"; break;
            }else{
                rezultat = num1/num2;
            }
            cout << rezultat << endl;

            break;
```

everything  is working as expected.

Can anyone clarify what is going here from program logic side of things?  Is this means that else block of if statement is being run even if condition is met?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because if `num2` is `0` then the message is printed and after that it tries to do `cout << result << endl;` with result still being uninitialized

another possible fix is:

```
case '/':

    if (num2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "num2 cannot be zero - division with zero is not possible!\n"; 
    }else{
        result= num1/num2;
        cout << result << endl;
    }

    break;
```

Comment: Thank You! I just did not see that `cout << result << endl;` was outside of brackets...

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, if `num2 == 0`, then your message is sent to `cout`, but `result` isn't assigned a value. Execution continues with the line just after the `else` block:

```
cout << result << endl;
```

thus generating the error.

In the modified code, if `num2 == 0` then the two statements on the line

```
cout << "num2 cannot be zero - division with zero is not possible!\n"; break;
```

get executed. The `break;` statement causes execution to continue after the end of the entire `switch` block, so `cout << rezultat << endl;` never gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Hope your issue is clarified above however you may probably remove the redundant
 `cout<<result<<endl;` from `Switch` statement and put it outside the same, because it's common part in all the `case` and does nothing but displays the computation result, something like

```
 switch(operation)
 {
   case '+': /*your computation here*/ break;
   case '-': /*your computation here*/ break;
   case '*': /*your computation here*/ break;
   case '/': /*your computation here*/ break;
   default:  /*your message command here*/;
 }  
 cout<<result<<endl; /* since this line is common, and does nothing but prints the result */
```

Comment: that's a good way of coding that's it nothing else @hajrovica